# Can someone explain why this account was merged with my main account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

So I registered this account about two months ago, after I deleted my previous account that was associated with my main login.

I registered this account using a different e-mail address, I made up a different user name, and I didn't even upload a picture to change my avatar, and I absolutely didn't post anything for almost two months...

I thought I was invisible, nobody can know this is me, but on May 5, 2022, this account was mysteriously merged with my main account...

I swear I didn't do the merging, so it definitely was done by a moderator, but that's impossible, since I literally posted nothing at that time, how could you possibly recognize my identity?

Can someone please clarify this issue?

Comment: So that means: my account was hacked...

Comment: According to the answer, the only logical conclusion can be drawn is that someone cracked my passwords, which is easy because my passwords are predictable, I deleted other logins and changed my password.

Comment: There is another logical conclusion that can be drawn from the answer: *This was done by Staff* (i.e. an SE employee, for presumably internal SE reasons). Cesar has provided you with a contact form to pursue this further - I recommend you follow that advice; it might save you a lot of unnecessary password changing...

Answer (score 5):

Moderators are not able to merge accounts, that is only done by Staff. I can see the account was merged but cannot discuss details.

Please submit a ticket through the [/contact](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form so that we can specifically look at your account.